# pid file not created running spring boot application as systemd service

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, pid, systemd

I builded my spring boot application as executable using this spring boot maven plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

then I created the following systemd unit file to create the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=ss7tm
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=root
PIDFile=/var/run/ss7tm.pid
ExecStart=/root/ss7-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but when the application starts, file /var/run/ss7tm.pid is not created.

What is wrong? I am using spring boot 1.3.5

Comment: Did you run your application as root ?

Comment: yes, User=root in [Service]

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the documentation of `PIDFile=` in `man systemd.service`:

```
> systemd will not write to the file configured here
```

Your application needs to write to the PID file, `systemd` just reads from it.

If you aren't sure where find the documentation for a particular `systemd` directive, you can check `man systemd.directives` which lists all the directives and where they are documented.

Also, there's no need to include `User=root`. systemd runs as root by default.

Answer (score 1):

Building the jar with the spring boot maven plugin option executable = true generates an executable jar with embedded the following script in the first bytes of the jar.

From what I see this script launch the java command and create a pid file.

I supposed that $pid_file variable is obtained from the systemd unit file, but maybe I am wrong.

I am not a expert of shell scripting, so I am not sure which part of the script is executed by systemd.

I followed this documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/deployment-install.html

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#    .   ____          _            __ _ _
#   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
#  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
#   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
#    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
#   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
#   :: Spring Boot Startup Script ::
#

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ss7
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: ss7
# Description:       Spring Boot Starter Parent
# chkconfig:         2345 99 01
### END INIT INFO

[[ -n "$DEBUG" ]] && set -x

# Initialize variables that cannot be provided by a .conf file
WORKING_DIR="$(pwd)"
# shellcheck disable=SC2153
[[ -n "$JARFILE" ]] && jarfile="$JARFILE"
[[ -n "$APP_NAME" ]] && identity="$APP_NAME"

# Follow symlinks to find the real jar and detect init.d script
cd "$(dirname "$0")" || exit 1
[[ -z "$jarfile" ]] && jarfile=$(pwd)/$(basename "$0")
while [[ -L "$jarfile" ]]; do
  [[ "$jarfile" =~ init\.d ]] && init_script=$(basename "$jarfile")
  jarfile=$(readlink "$jarfile")
  cd "$(dirname "$jarfile")" || exit 1
  jarfile=$(pwd)/$(basename "$jarfile")
done
jarfolder="$(dirname "$jarfile")"
cd "$WORKING_DIR" || exit 1

# Source any config file
configfile="$(basename "${jarfile%.*}.conf")"
# shellcheck source=/dev/null
[[ -r "${jarfolder}/${configfile}" ]] && source "${jarfolder}/${configfile}"

# Initialize PID/LOG locations if they weren't provided by the config file
[[ -z "$PID_FOLDER" ]] && PID_FOLDER="/var/run"
[[ -z "$LOG_FOLDER" ]] && LOG_FOLDER="/var/log"
! [[ -x "$PID_FOLDER" ]] && PID_FOLDER="/tmp"
! [[ -x "$LOG_FOLDER" ]] && LOG_FOLDER="/tmp"

# Set up defaults
[[ -z "$MODE" ]] && MODE="auto" # modes are "auto", "service" or "run"
[[ -z "$USE_START_STOP_DAEMON" ]] && USE_START_STOP_DAEMON="true"

# Create an identity for log/pid files
if [[ -z "$identity" ]]; then
  if [[ -n "$init_script" ]]; then
    identity="${init_script}"
  else
    identity=$(basename "${jarfile%.*}")_${jarfolder//\//}
  fi
fi

# Initialize log file name if not provided by the config file
[[ -z "$LOG_FILENAME" ]] && LOG_FILENAME="${identity}.log"


# ANSI Colors
echoRed() { echo $'\e[0;31m'"$1"$'\e[0m'; }
echoGreen() { echo $'\e[0;32m'"$1"$'\e[0m'; }
echoYellow() { echo $'\e[0;33m'"$1"$'\e[0m'; }

# Utility functions
checkPermissions() {
  touch "$pid_file" &> /dev/null || { echoRed "Operation not permitted (cannot access pid file)"; return 4; }
  touch "$log_file" &> /dev/null || { echoRed "Operation not permitted (cannot access log file)"; return 4; }
}

isRunning() {
  ps -p "$1" &> /dev/null
}

await_file() {
  end=$(date +%s)
  let "end+=10"
  while [[ ! -s "$1" ]]
  do
    now=$(date +%s)
    if [[ $now -ge $end ]]; then
      break
    fi
    sleep 1
  done
}

# Determine the script mode
action="run"
if [[ "$MODE" == "auto" && -n "$init_script" ]] || [[ "$MODE" == "service" ]]; then
  action="$1"
  shift
fi

# Build the pid and log filenames
if [[ "$identity" == "$init_script" ]] || [[ "$identity" == "$APP_NAME" ]]; then
  PID_FOLDER="$PID_FOLDER/${identity}"
fi
pid_file="$PID_FOLDER/${identity}.pid"
log_file="$LOG_FOLDER/$LOG_FILENAME"

# Determine the user to run as if we are root
# shellcheck disable=SC2012
[[ $(id -u) == "0" ]] && run_user=$(ls -ld "$jarfile" | awk '{print $3}')

# Find Java
if [[ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]] && [[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]]; then
    javaexe="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
elif type -p java > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    javaexe=$(type -p java)
elif [[ -x "/usr/bin/java" ]];  then
    javaexe="/usr/bin/java"
else
    echo "Unable to find Java"
    exit 1
fi

# Build actual command to execute
command="$javaexe -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true $JAVA_OPTS -jar $jarfile $RUN_ARGS $*"

# Action functions
start() {
  if [[ -f "$pid_file" ]]; then
    pid=$(cat "$pid_file")
    isRunning "$pid" && { echoYellow "Already running [$pid]"; return 0; }
  fi
  do_start "$@"
}

do_start() {
  working_dir=$(dirname "$jarfile")
  pushd "$working_dir" > /dev/null
  if [[ -n "$run_user" ]]; then
    mkdir "$PID_FOLDER" &> /dev/null
    checkPermissions || return $?
    chown "$run_user" "$PID_FOLDER"
    chown "$run_user" "$pid_file"
    chown "$run_user" "$log_file"
    if [ $USE_START_STOP_DAEMON = true ] && type start-stop-daemon > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      arguments=(-Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true $JAVA_OPTS -jar $jarfile $RUN_ARGS "$@")
      start-stop-daemon --start --quiet \
        --chuid "$run_user" \
        --name "$identity" \
        --make-pidfile --pidfile "$pid_file" \
        --background --no-close \
        --startas "$javaexe" \
        --chdir "$working_dir" \
        -- "${arguments[@]}" \
        >> "$log_file" 2>&1
      await_file "$pid_file"
    else
      su -s /bin/sh -c "$command >> \"$log_file\" 2>&1 & echo \$!" "$run_user" > "$pid_file"
    fi
    pid=$(cat "$pid_file")
  else
    checkPermissions || return $?
    $command >> "$log_file" 2>&1 &
    pid=$!
    disown $pid
    echo "$pid" > "$pid_file"
  fi
  [[ -z $pid ]] && { echoRed "Failed to start"; return 1; }
  echoGreen "Started [$pid]"
}

stop() {
  [[ -f $pid_file ]] || { echoYellow "Not running (pidfile not found)"; return 0; }
  pid=$(cat "$pid_file")
  isRunning "$pid" || { echoYellow "Not running (process ${pid}). Removing stale pid file."; rm -f "$pid_file"; return 0; }
  do_stop "$pid" "$pid_file"
}

do_stop() {
  kill "$1" &> /dev/null || { echoRed "Unable to kill process $1"; return 1; }
  for i in $(seq 1 60); do
    isRunning "$1" || { echoGreen "Stopped [$1]"; rm -f "$2"; return 0; }
    [[ $i -eq 30 ]] && kill "$1" &> /dev/null
    sleep 1
  done
  echoRed "Unable to kill process $1";
  return 1;
}

restart() {
  stop && start
}

force_reload() {
  [[ -f $pid_file ]] || { echoRed "Not running (pidfile not found)"; return 7; }
  pid=$(cat "$pid_file")
  rm -f "$pid_file"
  isRunning "$pid" || { echoRed "Not running (process ${pid} not found)"; return 7; }
  do_stop "$pid" "$pid_file"
  do_start
}

status() {
  [[ -f "$pid_file" ]] || { echoRed "Not running"; return 3; }
  pid=$(cat "$pid_file")
  isRunning "$pid" || { echoRed "Not running (process ${pid} not found)"; return 1; }
  echoGreen "Running [$pid]"
  return 0
}

run() {
  pushd "$(dirname "$jarfile")" > /dev/null
  $command
  result=$?
  popd > /dev/null
  return "$result"
}

# Call the appropriate action function
case "$action" in
start)
  start "$@"; exit $?;;
stop)
  stop "$@"; exit $?;;
restart)
  restart "$@"; exit $?;;
force-reload)
  force_reload "$@"; exit $?;;
status)
  status "$@"; exit $?;;
run)
  run "$@"; exit $?;;
*)
  echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status|run}"; exit 1;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: That script when started by systemd will *not* create a pid file: systemd calls it with the "run" argument.